# Where To Save Payment App :: Custom Configurations

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am building a new Shopify Payments App. I have a draft public app with a payment extension configured. Our Payment App requires the merchant to configure some settings before they activate the Payment Provider on a Shopify store. (example: API Key to authenticate into our payment provider)

Right now, our Payment App provides a page with a form where the merchant can input the required settings. This is done by clicking on the "Manage" button when activating the Payment Provider on the Shopify store, following the documentation on the ["Onboarding a merchant to a payments app"](https://shopify.dev/apps/payments/onboarding-a-merchant-payments-apps) guide. Is there any way that we can save and retrieve that information on the Shopify side (ex: using Shopify API) or should I save that information on the Payment App side (Ex: by having a local database)?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

No you will need to maintain your own database for this on your shopify app.